# Unpredictable Java KeyCode when hitting alt + u on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, keycode

When I hit the key combination "alt + u" on MacOS the keyCode of the KeyEvent changes between 135 and 85. The latter should be the correct keyCode. Does anyone have an idea?